# Could not build module 'ObjectiveC' xcode 15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to build my project and I am facing the following errors in modules like "Redefinition of module 'Firebase' " and I don't know what's going on. I have removed pods and reinstalled them but nothing is working to fix the issue.

[image: The image has a list of bugs with their descriptions which I'm facing]